# whats the best way to trancode videos for streaming?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hlsl, mpeg-dash, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am building a video sharing site like youtube where users can upload a mp4 file and it is trancoded to HLS and then using flowplayer to serve the content via Cloudfront distribution and aws. I am noticing that I am getting network errors telling me to install abobe flash as well as network errors. Upon doing research I found that Chrome does not support flash and then I heard about Dash,  YouTube uses it. It is supported by most browsers. Does anybody know if Dash is the best way to go or do I need to continue working with hls.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you usually need to support both DASH and HLS streams to reach all your users.

DASH is typically used for Android and Microsoft devices and for Chrome browsers.

For apple devices, current apple iOS rules require you to use HLS on iOS devices for any video over 10 minutes, assuming your app is available on mobile networks which is nearly always the case:

> 2.5.7 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps HTTP Live stream.

(https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

The new(ish) CMAF standard means that you can have the same media stream for both HLS and DASH and only the manifest, or index files, need to be different. The one caveat is that for encrypted streams the devices much all support AES CBC encryption - this is now agreed to ve supported across most devices and vendors but it will take time until all users devices support this.